# Considering a Trek FX 7.7 - What else should I look at that is similar

Tags: hybrid-bike, shopping, trek

my Trek FX 7.5 was stolen a couple of days ago, and I'm looking to replace it with a 7.7.

I really liked the 7.5, so happy to stick with the brand and make, but thought I should consider other bikes that are similiar. Does anyone have any recommendations?

Thanks,
Giles

Comment: Is there any thing you really liked or disliked about the 7.5?Will they be remedied by the 7.7.

Comment: I feel for you man.

Comment: Have you considered moving away from a Hybrid. My first "Adult" bike was a hybrid, but after I wore through that, my next bike was a touring bike.  I really liked having drops more than flat bars, and found that a touring bike was great for getting around the city. Trek makes the 520, which is a really nice touring bike.

Answer (score 1):

Both the 7.5 and 7.7 are great bikes. An alternative would be a Specialized Sirrus. I have owned 2 Sirrus' and loved them. I only upgraded to a Specialize roubaix so i could participate in competitive road biking.

The difference between the 7.5 and 7.7 is pretty big. 7.7 has much better road worthy components and will be several pounds lighter.